# Golang addition

Tags: go, calculator, addition

I wanted to build a "addition tool" or calculator which starts at 0 and adds the number you type in to the current result.
Example:
You start with 0,
You type in 10,
Result: 10,
You type in 20,
Result: 30
and so on but I dont know how to build this code and yeah I am a total beginner sorry for asking so simple questions.
What I got is this:

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x int
    var y int
    x = 0
    //var z int
    //result = z
    fmt.Printf("Geben Sie eine Zahl zum addieren ein: ", x)
    y, _ = fmt.Scanf("%d", &y)
    fmt.Println(add(0, y))
}

func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

Comment: Start looking at the error diagnostic message thrown. Look the documentation for `Println` i.e what types it takes as arguments and see what you are passing

Comment: Don’t ignore errors.

Comment: Also note that `y, _ = fmt.Scanf("%d", &y)` is definitely not correct: you're passing an address of `y` to the function—ostensibly for the latter to write something to that variable,—and then make one of the values returned by that function overwrite the contents of that same variable. Please read the docs on `fmt.Scanf`.

Comment: It didnt not even show me any Problems beside that Printf looked strange due to the x at the end, which i removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x int
    x = 0

    for {
        fmt.Printf("Geben Sie eine Zahl zum addieren ein: %d\n", x)
        var y int
        _, err := fmt.Scanf("%d\n", &y)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        oldX := x
        x = add(x, y)
        fmt.Printf("SUM: of %d+%d=%d\n", oldX, y, x)
    }
}

func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the result of addition in a variable and re-use it:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var x int = 0
    for {
        var y int
        fmt.Printf("Geben Sie eine Zahl zum addieren ein: ", x)
        y, _ = fmt.Scanf("%d", &y)
        x = add(x, y)
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
}

func add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
```

Comment: This can't work, cause, from documentation:Scanf scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments as determined by the format. **It returns the number of items successfully scanned**. You are set the result of the `fmt.Scanf` to the variable where the input is stored. So `y` in your case will be every time `1`

Comment: @alessiosavi, sure, but I explained that mistake the OP was made in my comment to their question. The answer deals only with the stated problem and is not supposed to provide a polished ready-to-go solution; otherwise that'd be a homework-style Q&A session.